# Issue uploading iOS app to iTunes Connect: "Symbol tools failed"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am in the process of uploading my app to iTunes Connect.  As I am uploading to iTunes Connect, an error comes up, saying "An error occurred during upload.  Symbols tool failed."

I am very confused to why this error is occurring.  I've been able to upload builds to iTunes Connect previously without issue.  Our team added Placed framework in our app recently and I have a hunch that might be the issue, but I am not sure.  The reason I feel that Placed is our issue is because Xcode mentions that it has 0 Entitlements three times before the upload.

How do I bypass this issue?

Before upload (notice the Placed 0 Entitlements):
[image]

Symbols tool failed error, occurs shortly after pressing the upload button in previous picture:
[image]

Archive upload failed:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is likely to do with the framework bundle you've added to your app. What frameworks have you added to the app?

Comment: The last framework I added was Placed.  When I removed this completely from the app I was able to archive and upload.  I need to incorporate this framework at some point.  How do I add the framework and not have this troublesome behavior?  @mechdon

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Placed framework. Does it contain individual bundles? Check the .bundle file(s) and see if there is an info.plist file. If there is, remove the executable file from it. Also, have you tried to uncheck the "Include app symbols to your application..." when you upload your app?

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?

Comment: @Jameson I was not able to yet.

Comment: did u found a solution please Im facing that with linkedin framework

Comment: I found one solution that worked for me. Please try this. When you validating or uploading build uncheck “Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from Apple”

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this problem with XCode 9 and it appears to occur when you have third party frameworks or compiled .a libraries added to your projects build settings as it is unable to symbolicate these files.

Unchecking `Include app symbols` allows it to upload.

Answer (score 5):

To resolve this myself, Go to Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Remove all frameworks or folder with frameworks. No frameworks should be there!

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened when my hard disk was out of space, check out the logs.

Answer (score 0):

`pod install` command it will fix the problem